# How to configure HTML elements after .append-ing them using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noob needs help!)
In my code i try to append content to a modal window, but after appending I'm unable to work with the elements.
Here's JQuery:

```
$('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var temp = $(this).attr('id').split('^');
    var modal;

    if (temp[0] == "cat_admin")
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"post.php", 
            data: { message : 'modal_cat_edit' }, 
            success:function(result){
            modal = result;            
            $("#dialog").appendChild(result);
            }
        });
        if ($(this).attr('id') != "c_new") 
        {
            var cid = temp[1];
            var calias = temp[2];
            var cname = temp[3];

            $("#dialog").children("#c_name").val("cname");
            $("#c_alias").val(calias);
            $("#c_id").val(cid);
        }
        else
        {            
            $("#c_name").val('');
            $("#c_alias").val('');
            $("#c_id").val('');
        }
```

Here's the appended HTML:

```
<input class='n1' type='text' id='c_name' value='' style='width: 350px; border: 1px solid #5C9ACD;' placeholder='Название категории'/>
<input class='n1' type='text' id='c_alias' value='' style='width: 350px; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid #5C9ACD;' placeholder='Псевдоним'/>
<input type='hidden' id='c_id' value="">
<div id='c_del' class='det_button' style='float: none; width: 184px; display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px;'>Удалить</div>
<div id='c_save' class='det_button' style='float: none; width: 184px; display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px;'>Сохранить</div>
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: `appendChild` is not there... you have `.append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript doesn't wait for the AJAX function to be finished. It just continues with the script.

So put your

```
if ($(this).attr('id') != "c_new")
```

function into the success function in your AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the ajax request will take some time, and you're trying to work with the elements BEFORE they're actually loaded.

You should move your jQuery magic inside the ajax's `success function`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Ajaxcall is to slow, just move your code into the success funktion

Comment: No matter how fast the ajax call is, it will never be fast enough to make the op's code work.